# set_index not indexing in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

For a simple program below, I was expecting the 2nd output to be same as first..

Why is this not happening?

It's just a order change in `data1` and `data2`

```
columnList = ["PID", "Sec", "Util", "random"]

data1 = [('67123', 12, '85' , '100'),  
         ('67123', 112, '15', '100'),
         ('87878', 23, "95", '100'), 
        ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=columnList)
df1 = df1.set_index(["PID", "Sec"])
print df1

         Util random

PID   Sec            

67123 12    85    100

      112   15    100

87878 23    95    100
```

```
data2 = [('67123', 12, '85' , '100'),  
         ('87878', 23, "95", '100'), 
         ('67123', 112, '15', '100'),
        ]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=columnList)
df2 = df2.set_index(["PID", "Sec"])
print df2
          Util random

PID   Sec            

67123 12    85    100

87878 23    95    100

67123 112   15    100
```

Answer (score 0):

It is default displaying of `Multiindex`. You can temporary change it by set parameter `display.multi_sparse` to `False` with `with`.

> **Option**: display.multi_sparse
>
> **Default**:   True
>
> **Function**: “Sparsify” MultiIndex display (don’t display repeated elements in outer levels within groups)

[Available options](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#available-options) of `Pandas`.

```
#default options
#set temporary multi_sparse to True
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', True):
    print df1
    
          Util random
PID   Sec            
67123 12    85    100
      112   15    100
87878 23    95    100
    
#same as
print df1    
    
          Util random
PID   Sec            
67123 12    85    100
      112   15    100
87878 23    95    100

#set temporary multi_sparse to False    
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print df1    
          Util random
PID   Sec            
67123 12    85    100
67123 112   15    100
87878 23    95    100
```

If you want [set it](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#setting-startup-options-in-python-ipython-environment), use:

```
 pd.set_option('display.multi_sparse', False)
```

And reset:

```
pd.reset_option('multi_sparse')
```

Comment: I had set the option as :
 pd.set_option('display.multi_sparse', False)

And it still shows 2 rows in PID column for 67213 which I was expecting to be the in just one row and 2 rows in Sec column corresponding to 67213

Comment: It show same output with: `with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', True):
    print df1` and `with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print df1` ?

Comment: With False, both outputs show flat rows. With True, only the first output show as grouped view whereas the second is always FLAT.

I am seeing this in jupyter

Comment: I think it is desired output. It is right, because there is only difference in displaying `DataFrames` with repeating values in `Multiindex`. And `display.multi_sparse` set two modes of displaying - with showing repeating values in `Multiindex` by `False` and with `hiding` repeating 2.nd, 3rd., .. values by `False`. Maybe I not explain it very clear before, sorry.