# transform index to an other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this table.

```
                             child_2_1
parent    child_1 child_2_1           
crane_rec a       vd                 1
                  xx                 1
          v       ve                 1
                  vv                 1
weather   Current f                  1
          Wave    s                  1
                  x                  1
```

I want to have this :

```
                             
parent    child_1 child_2_1           
crane_rec a       vd                 
                  xx                 
          v       ve                 
                  vv                 
weather   Current f                  
          Wave    s                  
                  x
```

I try to save the index, and put it in an other dataframe unsuccessful... I try this df = df.T bit it's doesn't work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html):

```
df1 = df.index.to_frame(index=False)
```

Comment: I have ever try it, but I need to groupby the value at the same time. When I did  df.index.to_frame(index=False), the values in the first and the second are repeted

Comment: @olympe59 - It is expected, because also values in your index are repeated, only are not displayed.

Comment: ok, so I can't display the dataframe  I want ? Because when I do the groupby, the result is an index while I want just the group like a dataframe

Comment: @olympe59 - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35961320/set-index-not-indexing-in-pandas/35961699#35961699)

Comment: Thanks ! But how put the index of your example (PID  , Sec) in an dataframe, while keeping the arrangement of cells ? What I want is to display only once a value in the column

Comment: @olympe59 - do you think need not display repeating values lik in `MultiIndex`, like `'display.multi_sparse', True` ?

Comment: @olympe59 - I think it is wrong approach, in pandas is not possibble not display repeted values, only you can replace them by empty strings (what looks same, but it is different, because repeated data are lost)